# Property lists in elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I know little elisp, and I'm trying to figure out how to call a function that takes a property list as one of its arguments. The particular function is [`rudel-join-session`](http://rudel.bzr.sourceforge.net/bzr/rudel/branches/irc/annotate/head:/rudel.el#L868) from the [Rudel](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Rudel) package; I'm trying to set it up so Rudel will automatically join a session when Emacs starts. I'm not sure how property lists work, so I tried doing this:

```
(rudel-join-session (list :backend 'obby
                          :host "foo"
                          :port 6522
                          :username "username"
                          :color "blue"
                          :global-password ""
                          :user-password ""
                          ))
```

I'm getting the error:

> Wrong type argument: listp, obby

I assume it's from using property lists wrong. Any idea what the correct syntax is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that's a correct property list.  I notice this snippet in rudel.el:

```
(let* ((backend    (cdr (plist-get info :backend)))
```

That means that the `:backend` parameter is expected to be a cons cell.  All of the documentation I can find presumes that `rudel-join-session` is being called interactively, in which case the backend parameter is being generated programmatically, and I can't figure out from a casual perusal of the code just what it's supposed to be.  But the first thing I'd try is this:

```
(rudel-join-session (list :backend '(dummy . obby) ...))
```

That way the expression `(cdr (plist-get info :backend))` will evaluate to the symbol `obby`, which may be what's expected by the rest of the code.

Comment: I got an even more cryptic error message with `'(dummy . obby)`, but I discovered the magical `rudel-backend-get` function: `(rudel-backend-get 'protocol 'obby)` works. Anyway, this answered my main question (how in the world do you use property lists), so accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In addition, you may want to look at the content of `rudel-session-initiation.el`.

That file contains the variable `rudel-configured-sessions` the documentation string of which explains "session information property lists" in more detail.

In the same file, there is `rudel-session-initiation-adjust-info` which resolves backend references in plists by replacing them with the actual backend objects. What this function does is replacing a backend name like 'obby or "obby" with a cons-cell of the form `('obby . #<backend object>)`. Internally, this uses `rudel-backend-get` as you suspected.